# Checking if Cursor contains row results?

Tags: android, mysql

I'm having a lot of trouble with checking if a cursor contains any results.

I have a method that "removes" all rows from a given table which is here:

```
  Chevron.class
  public void deleteAllRecords(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME,null,null);
}
```

I then call a method which adds the SUM of the first row of the database which is here:

```
    public Cursor getRecalculate(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select SUM (" + SECOND_FIELD + ") FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        return res;
    }
```

My major issue is that if I remove all records from the database, res.getCount() still equals 1 but contains no information but then the method only returns 1 row anyway. So I'm stuck with how to check if the cursor has actual table data or just empty table data.

I've tried stuff like

```
if(res.getString(0) == null){
  .. Do code
}
```

but that doesn't work.

I get the error:

```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ceri.twostep_onecheck/com.example.ceri.twostep_onecheck.ShowGraph}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
```

Comment: `"select COUNT(*), SUM (" + SECOND_FIELD + ") FROM " + TABLE_NAME`, and see if `getInt(0)` is >0 or not.

Comment: @CommonsWare I get the same error saying : android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

Comment: You did not call `moveToFirst()` on the `Cursor`. The `Cursor` is always positioned before the first row when you get it. BTW, in the future, when you post questions to Stack Overflow involving crashes, post *the entire stack trace*, not just one line.

Comment: @CommonsWare Oh that explains it, Thank you so much. If you create an answer i'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know how many rows there are that match your query constraints, add `COUNT(*)` to the `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(whatever) FROM other_thing;
```

Then, move the `Cursor` to the first row via `moveToFirst()`, and examine the two values (`getInt(0)` for the count and `getInt(1)` for the sum).

Answer (score 0):

Use `getReadableDatabase()` instead of `getWritableDatabase()`.

**Try this:**

```
public Cursor getRecalculate() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select SUM (" + SECOND_FIELD + ") FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    return res;
}
```

**Read `cursor` value:**

```
// Move the cursor to the first row  if cursor is not empty
if(res.moveToFirst())
{
    do
    {
        // Do something with cursor

    }while(res.moveToNext()); // Move cursor to next row until it pass last entry
}

// Close
res.close();
```

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
cursor.getCount();
```

This should return at least one if cursor reads something or it will return zero.